# Fail2Ban plug-in is enabled in Munin but the graph images are broken. How to fix?

Tags: ubuntu, munin, fail2ban

I recently installed Fail2Ban on an Ubuntu 12.04.5 server and it’s working great. Now I want to setup Munin so it can monitor it and generate graphs/reports. I found that Munin has a built-in Fail2Ban plugin that can be enabled like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/fail2ban /etc/munin/plugins/fail2ban
```

Did that and restarted Munin like this:

```
sudo service munin-node restart
```

And waited 5-10 minutes for reports to be generated. And while there is a Fail2Ban area in the server report, all images are broken. Why? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I needed to adjust the Munin config to get graphs to be generated. I opened up the `munin-node` config file like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node
```

And then added this configuration option for Fail2Ban:

```
[fail2ban]
user root
```

Restarted Munin and in about 5 to 10 minutes new reports were generated with the images all in place as expected.